# Best way to always pass a configuration object as last parameter to a constructor

Tags: typescript

I have the following setup, where I can create a Grid from Tile objects, or coordinates via a static method:

```js
type Point = { x: number, y: number }

type TileConfig = {
  thickness: number;
  color: string;
}

type GridConfig = {
  origin: Point;
  gutter: number;
}

type TileConstructor<T extends Tile> = new (coord: Point, config?: TileConfig) => T

class Tile {
  config: TileConfig
  constructor(coord: Point, {thickness = 1, color = 'BLUE'}: TileConfig = {thickness: 1, color: 'BLUE'}) {
    this.config = { thickness, color };
  }
}

class TileWithTerrain extends Tile {
  terrain!: string
}

class Grid<T extends Tile>{
  tiles = new Map<string, T>();
  setTile(tile: T) {
    this.tiles.set(tile.toString(), tile);
  };
  config: GridConfig
  
  static fromPoints<T extends Tile>(
    coords: Iterable<Point>,
    tileConstructor?: TileConstructor<T>,
    { origin = {x:0, y:0}, gutter = 0 }: GridConfig | Partial<GridConfig> | undefined = {origin: {x:0, y:0}, gutter: 0 }
  ) {}
  
  constructor();
  constructor(tiles: Iterable<Tile>, config?: GridConfig);
  constructor(tiles?: Iterable<T>, { origin = {x:0, y:0}, gutter = 0 }: GridConfig = {origin: {x:0, y:0}, gutter: 0 }) {
    this.config = {origin, gutter} ;
  };
}

const grid = Grid.fromPoints([{x:0, y:0}], { origin: { x: 0, y: 10 }})  // ERROR: want the user to also be able to use standard Tile points with configs
const grid2 = Grid.fromPoints<TileWithTerrain>([{x:0, y:0}], TileWithTerrain, { origin: { x: 0, y: 10 }})  // OKAY
```

I understand why the error occurs, both can be undefined so when I just pass the config object its type clashes with the type of the `tileConstructor` parameter.

I don't want the user to have to pass `undefined` or `Tile` when they use coordinates:

```
const grid = Grid.fromCoordinates([{ x: 0, y: 0 }], Tile, { offset: -1 })
```

Playground [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACg9gSwHbCgXigbygDwFxRICuAtgEYQBOANFCAceVVAL4BQbokUAKggDYQAwnCQAzBAHN0WNlCjAAFggDGAayQQAzloakKlANxyoKuPziUCW4JWSTj7TuGgBxOwBMR4qTMwnLKWQCeGRgY3lJImBgKj0mIzYnLmg+QW8bSiIVYEsAHh4oCBxYpA8tXgEIAD4ZTQB3KAAKM0sPEMQUWjMfSQB+AjThUQlJAEp0Wp4OFX4AQx1KwVl5HtHBqu9Rkx7M7NzKFrg2jrDaTCVVDW0KjABGbvNLGQByACEAGQBVAFEXlg26RGvgwF2U6k0OgID1MTysUHe3z+LAm-nk8kuWgAdGsQVgFODrjpHhZKKwIqwkjN5oshgB1BBKHhUShzZBFEoQMoVIYrBQstlIACE1ls9ipbFmCwq7gQHgKHNK5SWNTRCiqt0IEEaAFk5mA8pl7LQeNUmmMKVoIMAhk1gFVBqiTBjlNj7YJsVbgHaqljcgBlMVISTm2juiAWkwsCm4yQEWVeYGSEwmGxze0qKBiShwEihFBaBXFJU8qpm52wtq6KAASVirLIgjy+eA1WoFfDGVs+0sAxVXayOXypvb6PxgUk7NB+AADLR6DOWLQojFmBgZ6x454tr4AD6wOaUe1zfh5BM7yS1fdEMoQCSaDx+CfBLCz+d4RfL6L1ggb9jyVF-ygHZRD2IdDkjVZQO7cCfQ9Ag6yoOZGwgAoy0eXo+3PJNINhJAwIOODtD7RCGybEdxzsSckD8N86A-JcoBXesZD-Lc5QvJ8qJfTA6IXRjmLiKA-ydMdMRxJMuKCJAv1XSgWCgClowlXZUEkTwZATLFs1zFstCaABtXiP3fRcAF1zigZ8kAIbB8GE98oDuP8UXkAB6NyoHqOYUAJaAiCtMlcigE8tDgKAKBClCFHCgLoDTMpD0fXkwE6YAKnqRlFDw0YtElaCmM8AAmTTPG0nM8zSwt6Sy5lKFZZAzSMviGIslUGSZAVkEs6zbNwX9HOc1gUSAA)

Comment: Use overloads, same as you did for the actual constructor. You have _two_ interfaces: coords followed by optional config; and coords followed by constructor followed by optional config. Then in the implementing signature the second value is undefined, or a constructor, or the config.

Comment: (Also note `Thing | Partial<Thing>` might as well just be `Partial<Thing>`, you have to deal with the possibility that any or all of the properties might be missing anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

afaik what you're looking for is simply not possible in Typescript.

Most modules you find around and most ones I ever written go around the "issue" by just passing a configuration object instead:

```
interface LibraryParams {
  param1: //whatever
  param2?: //whatever
  param3: //whatever
}

class Library {

  public something(params: LibraryParams) {
    //do something
  }

}
```

this way from the outside you can just pass whatever you need and you still can  use intellisense to know what you can pass to the `something()` method, and the order doesn't matter, which was your goal

Comment: It also has the added benefit that if the strict null checks option is enabled it'll prevent null/undefined on the parameter and warn when it can be null. Don't cover every single case but grealty minimizes chances of error.

Comment: and another added benefit is that your using typescript common practices instead of trying to overengineer something, which will make your colleagues happy